# Swift Parse PFQuery is showing no results with "equalTo" or "contains"

Tags: swift, mongodb, parse-platform, pfquery

I have an issue I cannot seem to resolve nor find the answer to. I am developing an iOS App in **Swift** using the **Parse** Library.

I have a **Mongo DB** thru **Heroku** and am able to write data to it using **Parse** with no issues. Now I need to *search* (query) the datastore. I need to be able to search for any name in the "column" called 'name', not just an exact title.

For example, "Ticket to Ride" is one name where "Ticket to Ride: Europe" is another. If a user searches for "Ticket to Ride", I need both to show in the query.

Right now, neither the "whereKey contains" nor "whereKey equalTo" is returning results.

```
let gamesQuery = PFQuery(className: "games")
print ("Searching for \(gameTitle)")
gamesQuery.whereKey("name", contains: gameTitle)
gamesQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
    if error != nil {
       print (error as Any)
       return
    }
    print ("Count : \(objects!.count)")
    if let games = objects{
       for  game in games {
           if let gameName = game["name"] as? String {
               print ("Game name :\(gameName)")
           }
       } 
    }            
})
```

I put some **Print** statements in place for debugging (and will be removing them and the **count** should this ever get to production.

- className "games" does exist (and I can run queries via a terminal window or a Robo 3T).
- key "name" is the gameTitles that have been stored such as "Uno", "Ticket to Ride" or "Monopoly"
- "name" is indexed
- Result set is always zero (whether using "equalTo" or "contains"

This has to be something simple I am missing. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
    let gamesQuery = PFQuery(className: "games")
    print ("Searching for \(gameTitle)")
    gamesQuery.whereKey("name", matchesRegex: gameTitle, modifiers: "i")
    gamesQuery.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print (error as Any)
            return
        }
        print ("Count : \(objects!.count)")
        if let games = objects{
            for  game in games {
                if let gameName = game["name"] as? String {
                    print ("Game name :\(gameName)")
                }
            }

        }

    })
```

With the "i" modifier you ignore the text case, maybe thats the problem.

Comment: Nope, but thanks for trying.  I tried that and got the same "zero count" results. Since posting this, I tried to just get the first object with a known value pair "minPlayers=2" and even that is not getting results. 

While I would go back and look at the configuration, the other functions (create user, createGame.save and others which right to the database are working. Even the login works, so I know I can read from the DB.

Comment: Resolved: I spent the weekend working on this on and off. I debug/printed various objects, expanded the logs, etc and could not find anything wrong. I changed the "className" / Object / Collection and was able to write to that table, but still not read from it. Finally, I deleted the cloud instance and recreated it. With no changes to the code, it started working, I was able to write AND read (and delete) from my database.